# Making all owner functions multi sig

Tags: solidity, multisignature

I have a smart contract with various owner functions such as these:

```
function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public virtual onlyOwner {
        require(newOwner != address(0), "Ownable: new owner is the zero address");
        _setOwner(newOwner);
    }
function pause() public onlyOwner {_pause();}
  
function unpause() public onlyOwner {_unpause();}

...
```

What would be the cleanest way to convert all of my owner functions to multi sig? Are there any standard templates I should be using?

Do I need to create a multi sig factory and instantiate a new multi sig wallet for each of the functions?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use an `onlyWallet()` modifier, which controls how other signatory functions can only be executed if the sending address is the multisig contract itself.

See:

https://johannlilly.medium.com/how-to-execute-functions-from-other-contracts-with-a-multisig-wallet-8b9b5ab0f680 (access to onlyWallet() modifier discussed here)

https://github.com/gnosis/MultiSigWallet/blob/master/contracts/MultiSigWallet.sol

You can also use this example as a reference to create multi-sig wallets:

https://solidity-by-example.org/app/multi-sig-wallet/

Answer (score 1):

You can leave your contract as-is. Set the address of your multisig as owner with `transferOwnership`, and then those methods with `onlyOwner` should be called via `executeTransaction` in your multisig (as by Gnosis Safe). You can do this as normal via Web/Etherscan with [Rabby](https://rabby.io/), or via CLI or via API with [0xweb](https://docs.0xweb.org/)